# understanding useCallback and setState

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have some simple lines of code to test the useCallback and setState hook. First I try to write like this:

```
const App = () => {

    const [count, setCount] = useState(0)

    const increase = useCallback(() => {
        setCount(count + 1) // Passing value to change state
    }, [])
    console.log(count)

    return (
        <div id="main">
            <h1>Count: {count}</h1>
            <button onClick={increase}>Increase</button>
        </div>
    )
}


export default App;
```

and then, passing the callback to setCount instead like this:

```
const App = () => {

    const [count, setCount] = useState(0)

    const increase = useCallback(() => {
        setCount(count => count + 1) // Passing callback
    }, [])
    console.log(count)

    return (
        <div id="main">
            <h1>Count: {count}</h1>
            <button onClick={increase}>Increase</button>
        </div>
    )
}


export default App;
```

I know it is weird to use useCallback in this situation, just for some testing. The question is that why I pass the callback to setCount, the Increase button work correctly, whereas the first one will just re-render on the first click

Comment: Because `useCallback` memoizes the first reference to `count` and does not declare any dependencies (which is logically incorrect, it should declare `count` as a dependency). So the function will always capture `count = 0`

Comment: Because the dependency array of your `useCallback` is empty, therefore the function is never updated and `count` is always equal to its initial value. It's written [in the doc](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecallback).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the first case `useCallback` closes over the `count` and at that time `count` was `0` so It always changes value to `1`

So to make it working you should add `count` dependency to `useCallback` as:

[`CODESANDBOX LINK`](https://codesandbox.io/s/serene-water-0n0qvl?file=/src/App.js)

```
const increase = useCallback(() => {
    setCount(count + 1); // Passing value to change state
}, [count]);
```

In the second case it is not taking the value from the closure instead it is taking the current value and adds one to it and set the value.

---

**`ADDITIONAL INFO`**

You can use [`react-hooks/exhaustive-deps`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html#eslint-plugin) eslint rule to know which dependency is missing and tell you how to correct it.

Answer (score 1):

`useCallback()` hasn't been used correctly here: the dependencies array should have `count` in it. So:

```js
const increase = useCallback(() => {
  setCount(count + 1) // Passing value to change state
}, [count])
```

With an empty array as a dependency, it will be memoized for the lifetime of the component and will not update the current `count` value.

Source: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecallback

[Code sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/setsate-with-usecallback-jpwv0e?file=/src/App.js)

On a side note, using `useCallback()` is "overoptimizing" in this case, we are complicating the code while the performance impact to the end users is not noticeable. I would only use it to prevent rerenders in complex views e.g. in a huge list.